# two function with one variable in controller of laravel5.4

Tags: php, laravel, instagram-api, guzzle

I work with api Instagram and I'm using access_token variable in indexx function that it is json result that server send,Now I'm Trying to use this variable in picture function and send HTTP to server with Guzzle what Can I do?
my controller has this Code:

```
public function indexx(Request $request)
{
    $code = $this->code = $request->get('code');

    try {
        $client = new Client();
        $res = $client->request  ('POST', 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'client_id' => 'client_id' ,
                'client_secret' =>  'client_secret',
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'redirect_uri' => 'http://hanie-asemi.ir/laravel/instagram/test',
                'code' => $code
            ]
        ]);
        $status = $res->getStatusCode();
        if ($status == 200) {
            $body = $res->getBody();
            $obj = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($body);

            $access_token=$obj->access_token;
            echo view('json')->with($access_token);

        } else {
            echo "status is not 200";
        }

    } catch (BadResponseException $e) {
        echo "error1";
    }

}

public function picture()
{
    $client = new Client();
    $res2 = $client->request  ('GET', 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=Access_token');
}
```

Comment: return the code from the index function and access index function insdie picture view

Comment: @Exprator can you explain more?

Comment: at the end of your index function return $code; and in picture view call function index() then you will get the code

Comment: define a private variable named access_token (`private access_token`) before any functions begin and then you can access the variable(assign to it or anything) using `$this->access_token`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way would be to writing to the `config` and reading from it

```
public function indexx(Request $request)
{
    ...
    $access_token = $obj->access_token;
    config(['app.access_token' => $access_token]);
    ...
}

public function picture()
{
    $client = new Client();
    $access_token = config('app.access_token', 'fallback token');
    $res2 = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token='.$access_token);
}
```

Comment: I give this error `Client error: `GET https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=fallback%20token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException", "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid (truncated...)`

Comment: What's the output for `dd($access_token)` in `picture()` ? Aren't you getting the updated access token?

Comment: yes I'm sure I Update access_token,when echo access_token I give fallback token

Comment: The access token will only be set in the `indexx` method and if that method isn't called, the `access_token` wouldn't be set and falls back to `fallback token`

Comment: I use session to save access_token